# How to move an item within a dictionary when the Key equals the order number?

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
var newDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

The int (key) within this dictionary is the oder number for the items.

So say I have a list like this

> { 1, "item1" } 
>   { 2, "item2" } 
>   { 3, "item3" } 
>   { 4, "item4" }

In my controller I pass what the old item order number was, and what the new order number should be.
So for example if I wanted to move "item3" to be the first item I would pass to the controller 3 (old order number) and 1 (new order number).
So my list would look like this:

> { 1, "item3" } 
>   { 2, "item1" } 
>   { 3, "item2" } 
>   { 4, "item4" }

Comment: Maybe you need simple list of strings?

Comment: I'm actually using classes, not strings.  I just said string to make it simpler to understand

Comment: Why not switching values only.

Comment: I can't just switch a value.  For the example I have above if I just switched "item1" would have the order number 3, when it needs to be 2.

Comment: @Ben. I think in the above example "item1" remains there. Key should remain 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  Thanks for all the answers, but unfortunately most of what was suggested wouldn't have worked for what I wanted.  However this is how I have managed to do this:

```
public void ReorderDictionary(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        var oldDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        oldDictionary.Add(1, "item1");
        oldDictionary.Add(2, "item2");
        oldDictionary.Add(3, "item3");
        oldDictionary.Add(4, "item4");

        var movedItem = oldDictionary[oldIndex];
        oldDictionary.Remove(oldIndex);

        var newDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        var offset = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < oldDictionary.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 == newIndex)
            {
                newDictionary.Add(i, movedItem);
                offset = 1;
            }
            var oldEvent = oldDictionary[oldDictionary.Keys.ElementAt(i)];
            newDictionary.Add(i + offset, oldEvent);
        }
        if (newIndex > oldDictionary.Count)
        {
            newDictionary.Add(oldDictionary.Count + 1, movedItem);
        }
    }
```

May not be the best way, but unfortunately I have to work with an outdated system.  But at least this works :D

Comment: I'm not working with a string in the dictionary, I am working with objects, but its just simpler to understand if I say I'm working with a string.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the type of thing you'd normally use a dictionary for. You could consider using a List instead of a Dictionary and use RemoveAt and InsertAt methods on the list. If your list gets very large you might need to consider an alternative way of doing things (for performance reasons) but for small amounts of data it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Look on this like this:

You don's change items order, but change a *value* that key point's to. The effective order of items does not matter in dictionary, but what matters are *keys* that point to values.

What you want is that next time someone asks for `newDictionary[1]` will recieve `"Item3"` like a content.

Example:

```
//swap 

string val1 = d[1]; 
string val3 = d[3]; 

d[1] = val3; 
d[3] = val1;
```

If you need, by the way, some specific order, there is [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

Comment: Yes I get thats what I'd have to do, but how?,  I mean I can simply change the order number of one dictionary item key, but how do I change the rest of the items so that I don't end up with multiples of the same key.

Comment: @Ben: you can not end up with duplicated keys in dictionary, it will raise an exception. I edited my code to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Swapping won't work.  If I just swapped like that then they would all be in the wrong positions.  In my exmaple item1 should end up as the second in the list.  If I swap, it will become the third in the list when it is item2 that should be third.

Comment: @Ben: if you care about an _order_ of items, you picked a wrong data-structure for that. dictionary is just a key-value store, order does not matter at all and does not warry you in any way when you are using it. after swap, you will be able to get val3 on request of key1

Comment: I didn't pick the data structure unfortunately.  I just have to work with what I have.  But I'm in progress of another way of doing this in a for loop which seems to almost work.  Just a few more tweaks needed.

Comment: @Ben: you can order on client side, based on key. or from C# return an ordered List<T>, which is nothing else then projection of your dictionary data, ordered by key

Comment: Well its ok now thanks.  I've just finished what I was working on.  I've posted it at the bottom of this question.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried something in a Console application. Hope this gives you what you are looking for:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dictionary.Add(1, "item1");
        dictionary.Add(2, "item2");
        dictionary.Add(3, "item3");
        dictionary.Add(4, "item4");

        Dictionary<int, string> sortedDic = ResortDictionary(dictionary, 1, 4);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> row in sortedDic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: " + row.Key + "  Value: " + row.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, string> ResortDictionary(Dictionary<int, string> dictionary, int oldOrderNumber, int newOrderNumber)
    {
        string oldOrderNumberValue = dictionary[oldOrderNumber];
        string newOrderNumberValue = dictionary[newOrderNumber];

        dictionary[newOrderNumber] = oldOrderNumberValue;
        dictionary[oldOrderNumber] = newOrderNumberValue;

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have it a bit shorter use foreach in your reordering method:

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> ReorderDictionary(Dictionary<int, string> originalDictionary, int newTopItem)
{
    // Initialize ordered dictionary with new top item.
    var reorderedDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {{ newTopItem, originalDictionary[newTopItem] }};
    foreach (var item in originalDictionary)
    {
        if (item.Key == newTopItem)
        {
            // Skip the new top item.
            continue;
        }

        reorderedDictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    return reorderedDictionary;
}
```